# How to make two random generators with different seeds

Tags: java

I need to have two separate generators with different seeds. This code would produce two same seeds.

```java
long seed=System.currentTimeMillis();
long seed2=System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(seed+","+seed2);
```

Output:

```
[12:33:28 INFO]: 1604403208374,1604403208374
```

What is the best way to make two different seeds?

Comment: You could for example add 143 to one of them (or any other number you like).

Comment: Well would it be an okay thing to do? I am not really concerned about security right now as long as they are unique. But if security actually were a concern, is this still valid?

Comment: Or use `java.util.Random`.

Comment: If security is a concern, use `SecureRandom`.

Comment: Okay I went with java.util.Random for now. 
`Random x=new Random();`
        `long seed=x.nextInt();`
        `long seed2=x.nextInt();`

Answer (score 1):

## Make two random generators with different seeds

You asked:

> How to make two random generators with different seeds

…and you implied you might concerned about getting more truly random number generator.

For a a [cryptographically-strong random number generator (CPRNG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator), use [`SecureRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/SecureRandom.html) class.

Pass the seed to the constructor.

```
new SecureRandom( seedA )
```

So, in your case:

```
    byte[] seedA = this.getSeed() ; 
    SecureRandom randomA = new SecureRandom( seedA ) ;
    
    byte[] seedB = this.getSeed() ; 
    SecureRandom randomB = new SecureRandom( seedB ) ;
```

Here is a complete example app.

```java
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

import java.security.SecureRandom ;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Ideone app = new Ideone() ;
        app.demo() ;
    }
    
    private void demo()
    {
        byte[] seedA = this.getSeed() ; 
        SecureRandom randomA = new SecureRandom( seedA ) ;
        
        byte[] seedB = this.getSeed() ; 
        SecureRandom randomB = new SecureRandom( seedB ) ;
        
        System.out.println( "randomA.nextInt() = " + randomA.nextInt() ) ;
        System.out.println( "randomB.nextInt() = " + randomB.nextInt() ) ;
    }
    
    private byte[] getSeed() 
    {
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID() ;
        long most = uuid.getMostSignificantBits() ;
        long least = uuid.getLeastSignificantBits() ;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream( bos) ;
        try 
        {
            dos.writeLong( most );
            dos.writeLong( least );
            dos.flush() ;
        } catch ( IOException e )
        {
            System.out.println( e ) ;
        }
        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        return bytes ;
    }
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/pCha5G).

> randomA.nextInt() = 1597393916
>
> randomB.nextInt() = -1606028693

## Not unique

You mentioned in a comment:

> as long as they are unique

"Unique" means the same number will never be generated twice. That is *not* a promise made by a random-number generator. Repeats will happen with a random number generator, as they should.

If you want a universally unique identifier, well, use a [universally unique identifier (UUID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

## Best way to make two different seeds

You also asked:

> What is the best way to make two different seeds?

I have no idea. Security is not my strong suit.

For fun, in the code above, I thought to let the [`UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html) class produce a random-based ([Version 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random))) universally unique identifier (UUID) value. A UUID is a 128-bit value. In Java this value is stored internally as a pair of 64-bit `long` integer primitive numbers. In Version 4, 122 of those 128 bits are randomly-generated. So I retrieved both of those `long` numbers, and converted to an array of `bytes`. Caveat: I have no idea if this is a good or bad idea.

You can do something similar to generate any `byte[]` you want to invent.

Comment: I did not downvote. However, studying the idea and (even most recent) definitions of UUIDs and their generation, you should probably mention that they also do NOT guarantee to produce different results when used multiple times; even less the older definitions.